# Tensorflow Model for Image similarity detection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I have just started playing with tensor-flow .I am searching algorithm or code in tensor-flow or any other that can help me regarding following problem.
There are 10,000 images in my folder and i want to show them in my app.I dont want the similar images to be shown. For instance i have 10 selfie at a same place so i just want to show 1 instead of 10. We can take the example of google photo app or apple photo library.I also have tried some hash algorithm but for some images they failed to show results.Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the 
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour),
 have a look around, and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) ,
 in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
 and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: If you post your data and some code you have, I'd be happy to take a look and provide you with more specific advice.

Comment: Any update? How'd it go?

Comment: I have not found the optimum solution but yes as of now phash algorithm works with similar images. But for accuracy it is not the way to be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

[K-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) is a good clustering algorithm. It would allow you to group images in clusters, so that you could only show one image from each cluster. It is availabile in [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).